# Using form api to store google map location

Tags: forms

Is it possible to use form api (write codes) to display and store google map Latitude and Longitude? Most of the modules available is to add new google map field to drupal content type.
I don't want to use drupal content type to store as a node. i wish to store the location using db_insert.
Thanks

Comment: Short Answer would be "yes" I guess. Depending on your skills you can do pretty much whatever you want using Form API.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'm having no clue on how to do it since i couldnt find any form api type for maps or other module i can use. Are you able to share some idea on how to do it? Thanks

Comment: You're question is rather broad. I would advise you to add more information about what you want to achieve, what you have already tried, and in what way that has failed. Please refer to the [Help Center](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) for details on how to ask questions that will more probably receive good answers.

Comment: Regarding a Form API type for maps: I know of nothing like that either. If you want to achieve something like that using Form API you would have to write it yourself I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are couple of ways of doing this. You would need to install [Geofield](http://drupal.org/project/geofield) which has a Form API element that can be used as such:

```
$form['location'] = array(
  '#type' => 'geofield_latlon',
  '#title' => t('Location'),
);
```

That'll give you a start to work from. I'm looking at embedding a clickable Google map using the [GMap](http://drupal.org/project/gmap) module as follows:

```
$form['contact_us']['map'] = array(
  '#description' => t('Enter your location to be displayed as a Google map.'),
  '#type' => 'gmap',
  '#title' => t('Location'),
  '#settings' => array(
    'zoom' => 8,
    'id' => 'location_map',
  ),
);
```

It shows the map however that is about all, so far. But it's another starting point for you!